# The codebehind of aspx page is not under the page hierarchy

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, code-behind

When i try to drag and drop a specific asp.net page to my project , i notice that the code behind is n't under the page hierarchy in visual studio !

[image]

`EstimatedBalance.cs` is not under `.aspx`

---

**NOTE**:

I drag three files :

1. EstimatedBalance.aspx
2. EstimatedBalance.aspx.designer.cs
3. EstimatedBalance.cs

How to fix this problem ?

Comment: The file name is incorrect. It should be `EstimatedBalance.aspx.cs`. Try renaming it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The page you highlighted is a class, not the codebehind.  The CodeBehind should be EstimatedBalance.Aspx.cs, not EstimatedBalance.cs